# how to use $.ajax inside .load in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
 $("#").on("click",function () {

    $("#").load('', function () {


        $(".").on("click",function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this);

            $.ajax({


               .........etc
```

Can we use $.ajax function inside .load in jquery or is there any better way to handle this ?

Comment: Why do you need the `.load()` function?

Comment: ***What*** are you trying to do?

Comment: @Xander and   i'm loading a main wrapper div when clicking the menu of the site .So side does not refreshing

Comment: Yes, you can, just the way you are doing it. what do you mean by `handle this`? what is `$(".")` supposed to do?

Comment: i WAS try it but some conflicts are there

Comment: @KevinB there is a conflict when using this

Comment: What is the conflict?

Comment: I'll post my full code.

Comment: @KevinB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969134/how-to-use-ajax-inside-load-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to do that because you can't bind the click function on an element that hasn't been created yet.  What you should probably be using is event delegation:

```
$("#id").on("click",function () {
      $("#id2").load('');
});

$('#id2').on('click','.class', function() {
      //do stuff
});
```

This will find any click that happens inside of #id2, which already exists, and if it originated from .class, which may or may not exist at the time of binding, will execute the "do stuff" code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969134/how-to-use-ajax-inside-load-in-jquery please see this codes.I was posted in before....is three any wrong with that ?

Comment: wooooooooooooooooooooow.How do you know my mind ? lol....That is the reson dave.Very Thanksfull for such a answer